# How to determine if a point is within boundary?

Tags: c

I'm on a geographic project: 
you have a flight, within 10 miles of the coastline, the led on it will be triggered, otherwise remains.
We have generated 500 sets of coordinates, discrete numbers(longitude and latitude).

My first thought was creating a grid, each block was 3 mile x 3 mile, all land part will be 1, otherwise 0. And we calculate the sum of the nearest 24 blocks, if it is larger than 1. It would not trigger.

Then my manager suggest we can find the centroid of the polygon, then calculate the distance every time. 
Can anyone explain the algorithm here?

Sorry have not touch any programming for long time, and I'm a mechanical engineering, manager supposed this should be something fun to work on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can get the Lat and Long for the airplane you can calculate the distance from the coastline using Haversine formula, if reached within proximity do your task with led.

Comment: The final approach will be haversine formula, however, we just need a quick solve on this, since we do not have a cs major engineer at this point

Comment: How is the coastline described — do you have a set of (x, y) or (lat, long) coordinates, or something else.

Comment: I can give you a readymade solution, but it's in python, you can embed that in your C code, however, it is not easy. Here's a sample from python docs `from haversine import haversine, Unit

lyon = (45.7597, 4.8422) # (lat, lon)
paris = (48.8567, 2.3508)`

haversine(lyon, paris)
>> 392.2172595594006  # in kilometers

Comment: sets of (lat, long), about 500 of them

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [K-means algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering)

Comment: Hey Charles, I read it briefly. This is more sophisticated for this project and myself.

Comment: Tried to draw a simple line and do the centroid finding. Still thanks for your help!